# automatically keep trying to connect to telnet host until it suceeds (over ssh)

Tags: ssh, telnet, remote-management

I want to automate logging in by telnet on a remote host. The thing is, the `telnet` session becomes reachable a few seconds after `ssh` is available, i.e. `user@hostA telnet hostB` will fail until `hostB` is ready. How do I automatically retry to `connect` until it succeeds?

Answer (score 3):

You could tell your shell to loop until the command succeeds; in bash:

```
until ssh user@hostA telnet hostB; do sleep 2; done
```

When you log out successfully from `hostB`, the loop will exit. If your `telnet` session to hostB is forcefully disconnected (reboot; network disruption), the loop will resume/continue.